# How to properly insert images in appendix

Tags: graphics, appendix

I am new to latex. I am trying to make an appendix.tex section.

The code for the section is as shown below.

```
\appendix

\section{Graphical Results of Dual Branch Fusion}
\textbf{Experiment with default weights (Experiment a)}
$\alpha$ = 1
$\beta$ = 0.001
$\gamma$ = 1000

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{images/Dual_Branch_Images/trial_1/perceptual_loss.png}
    \caption{Total loss of combining the pixel loss and the ssim loss with weight 10000}
    \label{fig: Total loss in DenseFuse network with weight 10000.}
\end{figure}
```

But, no matter what I do, the images always start from the top of the page. If I put more than one image in a page, it will go to the next page.

Comment: Have you try `\begin{figure}[h]`?

Comment: @Tom That's not a good suggestion and LaTeX will override the `h`.

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a complete minimal example people can compile. If you don't want the picture to move, don't use `figure`. Instead, use, say `center` and `\captionof` from either the `caption` package or `capt-of`. `figure` is a float. It is meant to 'float' to the best position LaTeX can find (according to its lights, of course).

Comment: Without knowing your images, they might be too large. You could replace the width-option by e.g. `heigth=10cm`, or `height=.3\textheight` .

Comment: Hello I tried with ` \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth{images/Dual_Branch_Images/trial_1/perceptual_loss.png}`also. There is no difference in the output. 
The size of my image is 800 x 350.

If someone can post a link where a proper apendix.tex file is written with images, that will be more helpful.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I know. And `h` will be changed to `ht`. But then people ask why the float isn't here when they only specified `h` ....

Comment: @JohnKormylo But it's still, as far as I understand it, not recommended to use it as the sole specifier for a float. Especially if you're trying to get multiple images onto the same page as the OP is. If you don't make them floats in the first place, you can use several without hassle. And it is better not to write `h`, in my possibly erroneous opinion, if that actually means `ht` as it is just less clear than it could be. I'm not saying what will or won't fit where in this particular case.

Comment: @cfr - But it was a good suggestion, just not as good as using [ht].

Comment: @JohnKormylo The general rule, as I understand it, is not to use `h` as a sole specifier for a float. It wasn't a *bad* suggestion, but I don't think it was a *good* suggestion either.  But are we actually really disagreeing? This seems to be getting blown somewhat out of proportion unless I've completely missed some crucial fact about the discussion.

Comment: I just thought @Tom deserved a little credit for his suggestion.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you, John, I know [h] is probably not always suitable to solve the problem. But for somebody may not know well of the concept of float in latex, this is probably the first thing he can try.